# How to deal with localStorage for multiple users?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

In the event that you want to store user-dependent data in `localStorage` (e.g. because multiple users can use the same browser for your site), how do you typically deal with this scenario?

Let's imagine that I am able to identify the user with something like a unique `userId` on the front-end side. I would probably do something like the following:

```
// retrieve the data
data = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem( userId ) ) || {};

// persist the data
window.localStorage.setItem( userId, JSON.stringify( data ) );
```

Is this a naive way of doing things?

**EDIT:**
After giving it a little bit more thought as per @MДΓΓ БДL and other comments, let's assume the data is sensitive. In that case the above example indeed is naive. Any ideas on how to deal with sensitive data in this case? Or is the answer perhaps: don't do it, save it on the back-end?

Comment: It's not _secure_, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: How confidential is the information?  Unless JSON has it's own authentication mechanism, a user may be able to easily spoof his identity.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: No, you are right about that indeed. I haven't thought this through well enough yet, but for now, let's just assume it's not sensitive data. Just some trivial preferences for instance.

Comment: @all: You know what, actually, let's assume the data IS indeed sensitive, because that's what I ultimately probably want to use it for.

Comment: 1. http://paul.kinlan.me/we-need-to-kill-off-the-localstorage-api/ 
2. How about encrypting data client side with ex. http://www.jcryption.org/ ? You use standard RSA key's there

Comment: @chester1000 About point 2.: that was exactly the kind of thing I wanted to use it for. Encrypt password client-side, etc. and storing the password client-side as well. Gonna read it more thoroughly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sensitive data should pretty much never be stored on the client.  Unless you can guarantee the physical security of the computer and/or guarantee that the logged in user on that computer will only ever be the one using the computer (both of which are usually NOT true), then don't store sensitive information on the client if you can avoid it.

It is much, much, much safer to store sensitive information on the server and require appropriate login credentials before providing that information to a browser.  You can then control the physical security of the data on your server and prevent any users from accessing data that isn't theirs.  Further, you can protect it in-flight with SSL.

If you really want to store something locally that is only available to one user and one computer and one browser on that computer, you could prompt for a password and use that password to encrypt/decrypt data that was stored in local storage.  Except for a temporary off-line activity, I'm currently unsure why that would be a better user experience than storing it on a server where it can be available to that user no matter how they access the internet.  In these days of mobile access, tablet access, laptop access, etc... it seems that the trend is more to store stuff in the cloud so a given user can get access to their data via any internet access means they might use rather than requiring them to use the exact same computer.

Comment: Note that it is possible to store sensitive data on the client *if* it's encrypted and protected with a MAC in a non-malleable way. Your web framework might provide a way to do this; if it doesn't don't bother rolling your own unless you're hot stuff with cryptography.

Comment: Well, I kind of thought about encrypting the local data with a user password (i.c.w. AES, or something like that) as per @chester1000's comment underneath my question. I want to build upon [ZeroBin](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/) and similar ideas, which you may have heard of.