# Does HTML5 local storage separate data per user?

Tags: html, local-storage

If a website stores a value in local storage for a user on a machine, then later another user signs onto that machine and browses to the site, will the site see and overwrite the first user's value, or will local storage be empty because it's a different user?

(This is a similar question, but no one ever answers the first part: [How to deal with localStorage for multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322389/how-to-deal-with-localstorage-for-multiple-users))

Comment: When you say "different user" I presume you mean different user on the OS level?

Comment: OS and \ or browser (some browsers you can sign in too)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To clarify: the OP is asking what happens with `localStorage` when two user profiles access the same site. The quick answer: they do not collide.

`localStorage` is stored separately for each browser user profile, just like cookies, passwords, stored form data, etc. If two people log into different accounts on a shared computer and both visit the same site, each person's `localStorage` data will be stored in a separate place.

**However**, this should [not be used to store sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322740/1106901)! Also, when a user logs out the `localStorage` will still be there.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9se9bb6r/2/).

Comment: I've changed the correct answer to this one. Using your fiddle from two different accounts on the same computer indeed shows that local storage keeps data separate between URLs AND users. 

Which is annoying if you want users on shared network machines to be able to reuse large downloaded browsable datasets :-(

Comment: Ah, that is the use case! That would be awesome.

Comment: @josiahDaniels I've used local storage and it is overwriting the values when 2nd user logs in through second browser.

Comment: This is no true. When you access a website with two differente Google Accounts on Chrome for example, it will have different localStorage scopes because its generate two different user folders. But when you access with a login page on a web page with two different accounts, it will share the same localStorage between all the users

Answer (score 2):

LocalStorage is a simple key-value store, in which the keys and values are strings. **There is only one store per domain**. This functionality is exposed through the globally available localStorage object. The same applies to sessionStorage.

There aren't user storage component provided by the localStorage system, but if you need you can manage in your html page using javascript

```
<script>

    // Using localStorage
    // store data
    localStorage.lastName = "LastName";
    localStorage.firstName = "FirstName";
    localStorage.location = "Location";
    // retrieve data
    var lastName = localStorage.lastName;
    var firstName = localStorage.firstName;
   var location = localStorage.location;
</scipt>
```

this [w3c resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)  and this [from html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/) could be useful

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any URL reference for this claim? I can't find anything online about users per browser per domain..

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't think this is correct. localStorage is separated out by user profile. i think that is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: This answer is correct if the same users are logging onto the same website using different website logins, but the same OS login.  Different OS logins will not share the same localStorage. It is explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage