# Does JavaScript have a function that combines localStorage with user sessions?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a web application that allows user to like and unlike other users' posts. I am currently keeping track if a post should be liked or unliked through JavaScript's `localStorage`, but if another user on the same device logs in, the information from the previous user stays in the console, which prohibits other users from liking the post. 
Is there a JavaScript function that combines `localStorage` and user sessions or some other way to implement this? (`sessionStorage` is not what I want and [How to deal with localStorage for multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322389/how-to-deal-with-localstorage-for-multiple-users?noredirect=1&lq=1) did not help.)

JavaScript code that currently uses `localStorage`:

```
var liked = "false";

if(!localStorage.getItem('liked')){
    localStorage.setItem('liked', 'false');
}

function like(id){  
    console.log(id);
    console.log("like button is clicked");
    let likes = Number(document.querySelector(`#likes_num_${id}`).innerText);
    console.log(likes);
    let liked = localStorage.getItem('liked');
    if(liked === 'false'){
        let likeNum = likes +=1;
    
        //like the post
        fetch(`/like/${id}`,{
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                likes: likeNum
            })
        })

        localStorage.setItem('liked', 'true');
    }else{
        console.log("should be unliking");
        let likeNum = likes -=1;
    
        //unlike the post
        fetch(`/like/${id}`,{
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                likes: likeNum
            })
        })
        
        localStorage.setItem('liked', 'false');
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using database to store that ?

Comment: Why not just reset the `localStorage` when a users logs in/out?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, wouldn't that delete the ```localStorage``` from the previous user?

Comment: @bogdanoff, would I have to create another model for likes to do that? Is there a way to do it without having to create another model?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? To @bogdanoff's point, if you need to store state across sessions you should be using a database

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, I want it to save for a particular user.

Comment: @user19590524 I don't think you need another model, create new field in posts model, call it 'likes' which will be array of liked user ids.

Comment: Why would a different user on a separate OS login use the same browser profile? Why would they see _anything_ that other users have set in their browser on the same computer? Unless you mean "two people using the same computer, with the same login, and the same browser profile" in which case: that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, when I try it on my own computer using two different logins, the localStorage from the previous user affects the second user.

Comment: Did you make both users share the same browser proflie? Because they _really_ shouldn't.

Comment: Using localstorage you cannot store data for a particular **user**, just a particular **machine**. On my desktop right now I have 3 different PC's running at the same time and I am using all 3 at the same time (keyboard/mouse sharing so that it looks like a 3 monitor setup but it is actually 3 different PCs connected by LAN). If I move from one PC to another my likes will be very different. Not to mention that I have an iPhone and two iPads so I have 5 separate machines that I login to at the same time

Comment: @slebetman, but hypothetically if both users used the same browser, the application wouldn't work correctly? I just want to make sure that it won't be an issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about both user. I'm talking about a scenario you are not thinking about: **one** single user using 7 different browsers on 5 different machines! The only solution is to stop doing it in the frontend and store the data you need on your server

Answer (score 1):

Add another key to `localStorage` that stores some account identifier for the currently logged-in user.

If at any point that `localStorage` value holds an other than the currently logged-in user, clear your entire `localStorage` and start over fresh. Notice that this may happen through explicit login/logout actions, but also in any other way.

Comment: what kind of key would I have to add to ```localStorage``` and how would I pass that to the user?

Comment: Well how do your user sessions work? Do you have anything such as a session or account identifier?

Comment: I am using Django models.